# How can I know if a character is available on a bitmap font?

Tags: bash, scripting, special-characters

### Update

As nobody has still given a good enough answer, I will reformulate it:

**How would I know within a shell script in Linux if there's support in the current *bitmap font* for a given unicode character?**

That's it: not within gnome-terminal with its fancy TTF support and different charsets: the plain metal tty without X.org

### Old question (may clear out something in the above sentences)

I am writing a program with special characters in it.
Characters like װאבדג (hebrew).

Using some Ubuntu I had handy here I could get them to work inside the X environment (inside gnome-terminal). In rxvt, I get strange characters instead of what I have in the file; and in bare xterm I get *some* of them.

The file itself may be just as simple as

```
letters="⅄ႥႣႬזלבגװאבדגהוזחטענסףמלךלכפץצקႠႣႤႥႬႫႹჄႾႨ"
letters=$(echo $letters | sed -e 's/./\0\n/g')

letters=$(for i in $letters; do echo "$RANDOM$i" done | sort -rn | sed -e 's/[0-9]*//g')
echo $letters
```

In OS X it just shows "nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn".

Within the tty without X.Org started, it just shows a diamond.

In all the terms, I have

```
LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
```

Is there any way to know within the script if the chars will be shown correctly (I could implement some fallback if so), or if we can set the terminal to show it.

Comment: on OS X, if your program is already in UTF-8 or read in a string that is in UTF-8, then the output is all fine... this happens with the traditional Chinese and simplified chinese character sets, but not sure if it applies to your case too.  In the Shell setting, there is an option to choose the encoding.

Comment: @動靜能量 It is not. It was because of the bug that was mentioned by @mikerobi. It happens on the Linux terminal (not Mac's)

Answer (score 1):

You have a bug here:

```
echo $letters | sed -e 's/./\0\n/g'
```

**EDIT** (Since you mention you are on OS X I removed the part talking about GNU Sed)

With the version of set built in to OS X, `\0\n` means "0n" (the character zero and the character n).

You are replacing every character in your input, so you should not be surprised that you are not seing them in the output.

Comment: This is incorrect.  Gnu sed, which is what he is using, does not ignore `\0` as you claim; it actually treats it as equivalent to `&`.  So he is not replacing the characters at all.

Comment: @Porculus, thanks for the explanation, I've corrected my response.

Comment: So, matching against 's/./&\n/g' would correct the bug. Still, it does not show anything on the Ubuntu tty so, while it's right there was a bug, it does not answer my original question

Comment: @mikerobi I am working on both, so you were right, there's a compatibility bug. I first tried it on Ubuntu

Comment: @ssice, I think you are just running in to limitations in the terminal.  Everything works fine in gnome-terminal.  There is a separate "rxvt-unicode", and apparently there are limitations in xterm: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#getxterm

Comment: @mikerobi But what about non-graphical tty?

Comment: @ssice, I have a suspicion that the result will be no better than xterm, and possibly worse.  This is really outside of my area of expertise, but I suspect the problem is that the bitmap fonts used xterm, and non graphical consoles, just have incomplete character tables.

Comment: @mikerobi And how can I know about the character table inside the script, to implement a fallback?

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS X you can check Terminal.app for UTF-8 readiness:

```
defaults read com.apple.Terminal StringEncoding  # 4
defaults read com.apple.Terminal DoubleWideChars  # YES
```

Furthermore, Mac OS X uses FreeBSD sed which does not accept `\0`.

```
printf "%s" "$letters" | sed $'s/./&\\\n/g'
printf "%s" "$letters" | gsed $'s/./&\\\n/g'
printf "%s" "$letters" | awk -vFS="" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}'

# randomize letters
letters=$(echo $letters | sed $'s/./&\\\n/g')
# note the additional ";" after "${RANDOM}${i}"
letters=$(for i in $letters; do echo "${RANDOM}${i}"; done | sort -rn | sed -e 's/[0-9]*//g')
echo $letters
```

Comment: I can't find those entries in com.apple.Terminal: The domain/default pair of (com.apple.Terminal, StringEncoding) does not exist

Answer (score 1):

You may at least check if your current terminal emulator encoding is set to handle UTF-8 characters. And if this is the case your current bitmap font should support UTF-8 encoded characters as well.

```
LC_ALL= locale charmap  # UTF-8
```

The value of the `$TERM` environment variable may also give a hint whether your current terminal is capable of handling UTF-8 characters, e. g. rxvt vs urxvt.

And last but not least you may play around with tools such as `tconv`, `ttyconv` or `luit` to convert to & from UTF-8.

See:

- [Re: A call for fixing aterm/rxvt/etc... (tconv)](http://www.mail-archive.com/linux-utf8@nl.linux.org/msg05421.html)
- ["tail -f | iconv -fsjis" does not output anything (ttyconv, luit)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35662/tail-f-iconv-fsjis-does-not-output-anything)